# Add a posts meta-value to the permalink/url in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I am trying to build  a speaking URL for a custom post type in Wordpress storing event dates. I would like to have the following scheme for event-URLs:

`/events/2013-12-24-christmas/` `/events/2013-12-31-newyearseve/`

The date is ***not*** the standard published date, it is instead a date stored in a meta-field: the date on which the event takes place.

I tried to achieve it with a snippet I used to rewrite another custom post type and it looked promising - but the only problem is: I can't get the post-id to query for the meta values :(

Here's the rewrite code so far:

```
function create_post_type_events {
  [...custom-post-type...]

  register_post_type('my_events', $args);

  global $wp_rewrite;
  $permalink_structure = '/events/2013-12-24-%my_events%';
  $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%my_events%", '([^/]+)', "my_events=");
  $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('my_events', $permalink_structure, false);
}
add_action('init', 'create_post_type_events');
```

The date is obviously hard-coded and needs to be replaced.

I tried $post, $wp_query, globalizing, get_queried_object()... nothing seems to help.

So, how (*and is it actually possible?*) can I get the post-ID for further querying?

Comment: This is interesting. At first glance you want the date to NOT have a trailing '/' before the postname, only a dash '-', correct? Because my CPT's always default to /posttype/postname. Also, I have only seen post id's get meta data with $wpdb and a custom query like the way geo-data-store does it. I will be watching this post.

Comment: Can't you adjust the slug for this, that would make it so much easier. And a slug is meant for url's

Comment: @BenRacicot Sorry for the misunderstanding, but the trailing slash is not the issue here ;) I edited my question as I have seen I missed a slash.

Comment: @janw I know I could set the slug to represent this, but in this case the date strongly belongs to the title, it's the date of the event. I thought it would be better to have the event date and event title together.

Comment: Okay I get that, but still setting the *title* part and the *date* part separate will help to get the *title* if that is the slug rather then a postmeta. And even if you merge *title* and *date* in a slug, that's what it is for.

Comment: But apart from that - how to get the date or another value from a meta field? Even if the date *would* be the slug - how to get it? (It's not the posts published date!)

Comment: Yes! I understand now. This is a truly unique and valuable question and maybe a bounty could be set?

Comment: I need to get the answer to this too, as I'm having the same problem and can't fix it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209035/how-can-i-place-a-meta-value-in-rewrite-rule-for-custom-post-type